# MapReduce, adjusting the Mapper method

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm writing a simple Map Reduce program that counts the number of tweets sent per day during a sporting event.

```
def mapper(self,_,line):
    #Extracting the fields of csv line
    fields = line.split(";")
    #To choose the actual tweet we extract field[4]
    for field[4] in fields:
        time_epoch = int(fields[0])/1000
        #Extract date tweet was sent
        day = time.strftime("%d",time.gmtime(time_epoch))
        #For each date, count num of tweets sent
        #Since calculating the number of tweets sent each day
        #Shouldn't day be the key, and intermediate value be 1
        yield(day, 1)
```

And now the reducer code takes in the intermediate key,values and performs aggregation:

```
def reducer(self, day, counts):
    #For each day during the sporting event, calculate the total tweets sent
    yield(day, sum(counts))
```

**I was struggling to decide whether the key for the reducer should be the actual tweet or the day on which the tweet was sent. However, I came to the conclusion that since I want to calculate the total on each day, the specific day should be the key.**

However, I'm getting an error, I was wondering if there is anything obvious that I'm missing? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention your error, but `for field[4] in fields:` is not syntactically correct.

Perhaps you meant `if len(fields) >= 4:`

> However, I came to the conclusion that since I want to calculate the total on each day, the specific day should be the key

That sounds right to me